# How to create jquery UI dialog Buttons dynamically and map to function?

Tags: jquery

I took this sample piece of code from the below link

[How do I close a dialog using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354443/creating-jquery-ui-dialog-dynamically)

```
$(function () {
    $("a:contains('sometext')").click(function() {
        var NewDialog = $('<div id="MenuDialog">\
            <p>This is your dialog content, which can be multiline and dynamic.</p>\
        </div>');
        NewDialog.dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: "title",
            show: 'clip',
            hide: 'clip',
            buttons: [
                {text: "Submit", click: function() {doSomething()}}
            ]
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here instead of the value **doSomething** I need to use a variable.
For eg:- if i have a variable temp=confirm, the value **confirm** should be used there.
so when i clicked the button the function confirm should be invoked.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If your confirm variable is a function you can just replace click function with confirm:

```
Edit:

 $(function () {
    var confirm1 = function(){
        alert("confirm function 1");
    }
    var confirm2 = function(){
        alert("confirm function 2");
    }

    var temp = confirm1;


    $("a:contains('sometext')").click(function() {
        var NewDialog = $('<div id="MenuDialog">\
            <p>This is your dialog content, which can be multiline and dynamic.</p>\
        </div>');
        NewDialog.dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: "title",
            show: 'clip',
            hide: 'clip',
            buttons: [
                {text: "Submit", click: function(){temp();}}
            ]
        });
        return false;
    });

    //  Uncomment this line if you want to change temp function
    //  temp = confirm2;

});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nilgundag/SgFJk/4/

Comment: since the functionname will vary  i want to use a temp variable which will pass the functionname to the click event. So inshort i need to use a function name here.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code like below and it works..

> buttons: [
>                   {text: "Submit", click: function() {eval(temp)()}}
>               ]